# validate input with bootstrap not html5 message

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a modal with form, the form is a wizard step, if the inputs are empty the borderline change to red everything is ok with the firts and second step, but i have a problem with the thrid step be cause the validation change to html 5.

I want all the inputs change to borderline from bootstrap
!-- begin snippet: js hide: false -->

```js
var navListItems = $('div.setup-panel div a'),

            allWells = $('.setup-content'),

            allNextBtn = $('.nextBtn');



    allWells.hide();



    navListItems.click(function (e) {

        e.preventDefault();

        var $target = $($(this).attr('href')),
                $item = $(this);

        if (!$item.hasClass('disabled')) {
            navListItems.removeClass('btn-primary').addClass('btn-default');
            $item.addClass('btn-primary');
            allWells.hide();
            $target.show();
            $target.find('input:eq(0)').focus();
        }
    });

    allNextBtn.click(function(){
        var curStep = $(this).closest(".setup-content"),
            curStepBtn = curStep.attr("id"),
            nextStepWizard = $('div.setup-panel div a[href="#' + curStepBtn + '"]').parent().next().children("a"),
            curInputs = curStep.find("input[type='text'],input[type='url']"),
            isValid = true;

        $(".form-group").removeClass("has-error");
        for(var i=0; i<curInputs.length; i++){
            if (!curInputs[i].validity.valid){
                isValid = false;
                $(curInputs[i]).closest(".form-group").addClass("has-error");
            }
        }

        if (isValid)
            nextStepWizard.removeAttr('disabled').trigger('click');
    });

    $('div.setup-panel div a.btn-primary').trigger('click');
```

```css
body{ 
    margin-top:40px; 
}

.stepwizard-step p {
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.stepwizard-row {
    display: table-row;
}

.stepwizard {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

.stepwizard-step button[disabled] {
    opacity: 1 !important;
    filter: alpha(opacity=100) !important;
}

.stepwizard-row:before {
    top: 14px;
    bottom: 0;
    position: absolute;
    content: " ";
    width: 100%;
    height: 1px;
    background-color: #ccc;
    z-order: 0;

}

.stepwizard-step {
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
}

.btn-circle {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 6px 0;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 1.428571429;
  border-radius: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="stepwizard">
    <div class="stepwizard-row setup-panel">
        <div class="stepwizard-step">
            <a href="#step-1" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-circle">1</a>
            <p>Step 1</p>
        </div>
        <div class="stepwizard-step">
            <a href="#step-2" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-circle" disabled="disabled">2</a>
            <p>Step 2</p>
        </div>
        <div class="stepwizard-step">
            <a href="#step-3" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-circle" disabled="disabled">3</a>
            <p>Step 3</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<form role="form">
    <div class="row setup-content" id="step-1">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <h3> Step 1</h3>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label">First Name</label>

                    <input  maxlength="100" type="text" required="required" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter First Name"  />

                </div>

                <div class="form-group">

                    <label class="control-label">Last Name</label>

                    <input maxlength="100" type="text" required="required" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Last Name" />

                </div>

                <button class="btn btn-primary nextBtn btn-lg pull-right" type="button" >Next</button>

            </div>

        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="row setup-content" id="step-2">

        <div class="col-xs-12">

            <div class="col-md-12">

                <h3> Step 2</h3>

                <div class="form-group">

                    <label class="control-label">Company Name</label>

                    <input maxlength="200" type="text" required="required" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Company Name" />

                </div>

                <div class="form-group">

                    <label class="control-label">Company Address</label>

                    <input maxlength="200" type="text" required="required" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Company Address"  />

                </div>

                <button class="btn btn-primary nextBtn btn-lg pull-right" type="button" >Next</button>

            </div>

        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="row setup-content" id="step-3">

        <div class="col-xs-12">

            <div class="col-md-12">

                <h3> Step 3</h3>

                <div class="form-group">

                    <label class="control-label">Company Name</label>

                    <input maxlength="200" type="text" required="required" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Company Name" />

                </div>

                <button class="btn btn-success btn-lg pull-right" type="submit">Finish!</button>

            </div>

        </div>

    </div>
```

this is mi [fiddle](https://fiddle.jshell.net/fg7f1k2k/)

Comment: It's not the solution, but if you add the `nextBtn` class to the last button it does work. So it seems that it has something to do with the classes. The last `curInputs` is getting the previous two inputs, so that's another thing to look.

Answer (score 0):

*You need to write `class='nextBtn'` class in third level button and it's look like bootstrap validation and one more thing, if you post data using name of SUBMIT button then it's possible to add perfect bootstrap,*

so you change your type of submit button from `type="submit"` to `type="button"` and POST data through anchor tag and run program.

another solution, see example of anchor tag:

```js
function submit_form() {
    document.form_name_here.submit();
}
```

```html
<a href="#" onclick="submit_form(); return false;">Submit</a>
```

So here you can add bootstrap class in anchor tag `<a href='...'></a>` that's it.